# Estimate effects after exact matching

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, matching

I am working on a project, and I have to use matching. I decided to go to exact matching, and surprisingly I did not lose too many observations. But I have a dilemma about how to conduct the analysis after the exact matching.

I used the `MatchIt` package in R and read in a vignette the suggestions by Noah Greifer. In the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MatchIt/vignettes/estimating-effects.html#after-stratum-matching), he suggested that after stratum matching, `lm()` (for continuous outcome variable) or `glm` (for binary outcome) functions to estimate the effect of treatment.
It seems intuitive to me that a better approach would be using the mixed-effects model with subclass as a random effect. That is, it seems better to calculate the effect of treatment as `lme4::glmer(outcome~treatment + (1 | subclass), weights = weights, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = output.data)` instead of `glm(outcome~treatment, weights = weights, family = quasibinomial(link = "logit"), data = output.data)`.

Both approaches yield similar results, but I wonder which is correct. This problem might be trivial for some, but I am not a statistician, and I do not personally know any statisticians from whom to ask advice. I appreciate all the suggestions :)

Answer (score 2):

The coefficients from the two models refer to different theoretical quantities (i.e., estimands), so the models are estimating different things. The coefficient on treatment in the mixed-effects model is the subclass-specific log odds ratio, which is assumed by the model to be equal for all subclasses, and the coefficient on treatment in the generalized linear model is the marginal log odds ratio (i.e., the log of the ratio of the marginal odds).

The subclass-specific log odds ratio depends on pair membership and is a conditional estimand, but conditional on an ambiguous conditioning set (i.e., pair membership, not any specific covariates). It has no analog in a randomized trial and cannot be separated from the model used to estimate it. It will fall somewhere between the average marginal effect and the unit-specific effect but will be biased for both. If there is a lot of variability in the baseline odds (i.e., the odds under control), then the subclass-specific log odds ratio may be estimated with more precision than the average marginal effect.

The marginal log odds ratio is a contrast of the marginal probabilities of the event, which correspond to the proportion of units that have the event (or, the probability of a unit selected at random from the population will have the event). If you were to compute the odds ratio from a contingency table in a randomized trial, you would get the marginal odds ratio.

Because of the noncollapsibility of the odds ratio, these two quantities are not equal to each other in general (except when the subclassing variable has no relationship with the outcome, which is likely not true here). See [Forbes and Shortreed (2008)](https://doi.org/10.1002/sim.3362) for some discussion on the matter of marginal vs. pooled conditional odds ratios. Matching is best equipped to estimate marginal effects, so I recommend you follow the instructions in the `MatchIt` vignette to estimate the marginal odds ratio.

Note that with continuous outcomes modeled using linear models, the coefficient on the treatment in a linear mixed-effects model and a linear model will be (approximately) equal and have the same interpretation. It's the weirdness of generalized linear models that requires you to make this choice with binary outcomes.